# Firestore Android Simple Query, how to print out filtered text to console?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently following the documentation for simply querying using firestore, I have implemented my code but I am not entirely too sure how I can print out the fields to the console (I just want to be able to print out information so that I can visualise them for now). The documentation does not mention how I could do this?

My Code:

```
db.collection("holidays").whereEqualTo("startDayReference", "2021").get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {


                    Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot, and indicate the exact data you want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `document.getData()` returns a `Map<String, Object>` with the top-level fields and their values form your document. So you can print those values the same as for any other `Map`:

```
for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry: document.getData().entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() +
                     ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

The type of `entry.getValue()` depends on the type of field, so it can be a `String`, `Long`, or any other supported type. If you have nested fields, the top-level field's `entry.getValue()` for that shows up as another `Map<String, Object>`

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I have found another method in calling my data and managing it differently, however the method you have provided does work and could prove to be useful for others.